# Is it okay to use a device whose junction temperature is more than operating temperature?

Tags: voltage-regulator, impedance, temperature, thermal

I am searching for a voltage regulator which gives output voltage of 3.5V, 2A with input of 7.5V min. I have seen L6932 HIGH PERFORMANCE 2A ULDO LINEAR REGULATOR.
In the datasheet there is calculation for junction temperature which I got is 220 degrees celsius. But the operating temperature is 150 C. Is it okay to use this regulator ???
And the thing is that current of 2A flows only for certain period of time and then it decreases.

Comment: No. If you go above the maximum rating for the junction temperature, the silicon will have a thermal runaway. That means it becomes conducting and in result, it has even more current running through it, heats up even more and finally has a short to ground and burns out completely. This happens in milliseconds.

Comment: No, it's not okay. In fact, it should be lower by some margin since there are hot spots which should all be below the operating temperature. And even then, life span is usually degraded due to things like metalization migration. Keep well under, if possible. And observe the safe operating area chart, too, if available.

Comment: Look up "maximum" in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your title first, NO, you can not allow a device to exceed it's max operating temperature.

As to whether it is OK to use the device you indicated in your application, then it gets more complicated.

It really depends on the scale of "*And the thing is that current of 2A flows only for certain period of time and then it decreases*. "

If you only infrequently supply 2A for very short periods then the device will not heat up much and it will be fine. *(Though I would not be using a 2A device to drive a 2A load anyway...)*

You need to calculate the worst case power thermal deviation value. That is not necessarily the 2A power value though, nor it is the average power value.

When it comes to power, you really need to look at how much power for how much time.

There is a thermal gradient when power is applied such that your device will heat up to death temperature if the high load is on for a more than a certain amount of time. Obviously you need to derate that, and never exceed that value. Further, there must be sufficient time between power bursts to permit the die to cool down to some base level.

As others have mentioned in the comments, if you exceed those limits thermal runaway will likely kill the device, or worse.

Note however, most modern regulators also have thermal protection that is intended to shut the device off should it get too hot. However, this should never be relied upon as a design mechanism. Rather it is a backup protection should the ambient temperature around the regulator or heat-sink get too high, exceeding what you used for your safe thermal calculations.

**NOTE:** You CAN calculate using the worst case power value and use large heat-sinks and even fans to ensure the thing never gets too hot no matter what, but that can be serious overkill if the high load is only for 250uS once every six months. However, when backing off the heat calculation, you also need to take into account failure scenarios. If something gets stuck in the on position will the regulator catch fire. If the answer is yes, you should use additional heat sinking or protection circuitry.